# Go appending elements to slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, append, slice

I'm trying to **append** elements to a slice of a struct but it's returning error **invalidAppend**, that means that the first argument I'm passing is not a slice.

[Link to Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/K1NI33PhZ4H).

Here's the code:

```
type Item struct {
  Attr string
}

type ItemsList []Item

type IItemsList interface {
  GetItemsList() ItemsList
  AddItem(Item)
}

func NewItemsList() IItemsList {
  return &ItemsList{}
}

func (il *ItemsList) GetItemsList() ItemsList {
  return *il
}

func (il *ItemsList) AddItem(i Item) {
  il = append(il, i)
}
```

I can't figure how is the correct way to proceed with this append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the first argument I'm passing is not a slice

The first argument is a pointer to a slice.

```
type ItemsList []Item

func (il *ItemsList) AddItem(i Item) {
  il = append(il, i)
}
```

The first argument is a slice.

```
func (il *ItemsList) AddItem(i Item) {
    *il = append(*il, i)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/Se2ZWcucQOp

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> Address operators
>
> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x.